# javascript only works on page reload (rails, turbolinks installed)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have this link

```rb
<%= link_to "contact", ecrire_message_path %>
```

That page contains:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    // some correct javascript here
});
```

The javascript doesn't work when I click on the link. It only works after page reloads.

turbolink gem is installed and included.

I don't know how to add to the `link_to` element not to use turbolinks.

Thanks

Comment: @NMPennypacker: same. I need to reload.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
<%= link_to "contact", ecrire_message_path, data: { turbolinks: false } %>
```

[From official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#how-turbolinks-works):

> If you want to disable Turbolinks for certain links, add a `data-turbolinks="false"` attribute to the tag:
>
> ```
> <a href="..." data-turbolinks="false">No turbolinks here</a>
> ```